# Can't convert stored procedure to Linq expression successfully

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How can I convert this SQL Server stored procedure to a linq expression? I've got a couple of mistakes but don't know how to fix them.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
    @MatterNumber NVARCHAR(20)
AS
    DECLARE @ClientNumber INT = (SELECT TOP 1 LeadPlaintiffNumber 
                                 FROM [dbo].[vw_cmp_case_numbers] 
                                 WHERE MatterNumber = @MatterNumber)

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        defendantid, 
        defendantcode, 
        defendantname DefendantName 
    FROM   
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             fmrp.employerid DefendantId, 
             fmrp.employercode DefendantCode, 
             fmrp.employername DefendantName 
         FROM   
             vw_mpid_records fmr 
         LEFT JOIN 
             vw_mpid_records_products fmrp ON fmr.recordid = fmrp.recordid 
         INNER JOIN 
             vw_cmp_event_history fceh ON fmr.jobsitecode = fceh.jobsitecode 
                                       AND fmr.startdate < = fceh.enddate 
         WHERE  
             fceh.clientnumber = @ClientNumber 
             AND fmrp.employerid IS NOT NULL 
             AND fmrp.employercode IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP BY 
             fmrp.employerid, fmrp.employercode, fmrp.employername) yyy 
ORDER BY 
    defendantname
```

Here is what I have so far for the linq but there is a error at

```
fmr.StartDate <= fceh.EndDate
```

and then I'm not sure about the group by as well

```
var @clientNumber = (from ccn in context.VwCmpCaseNumbers where ccn.MatterNumber == text select ccn).Take(1);

var innerQuery = from fmr in context.VwMpidRecords
                 join fmrp in context.VwMpidRecordsProducts on fmr.Id equals fmrp.Id
                 into gj
                 from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join fceh in context.VwCmpEventHistorys on fmr.JobsiteCode equals fceh.JobsiteCode && fmr.StartDate <= fceh.EndDate
                 where fceh.ClientNumber = @clientNumber &&
                       fmrp.EmployerID != null && 
                       fmrp.EmployerCode != null
                 group fmrp.by fmrp.EmployerID && fmrp.EmployerCode && fmrp.EmployerName

var outerQuery = (from r in innerQuery 
                  select new 
                         {
                             EmployerId = r.EmployerID,
                             EmployerCode = r.EmployerCode,
                             EmployerName = r.EmployerName
                         }).OrderBy(obj => obj.DefendantName);

var viewModel = outerQuery.Select(obj => new SelectOption 
                                             {
                                                   Text = obj.DefendantCode,
                                                   Value = obj.DefendantId,
                                             });
```

Here are the lines that show the errors

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's worth to do join like `on fmr.JobsiteCode equals fceh.JobsiteCode` and  move `fmr.StartDate <= fceh.EndDate` to the `where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ doesn't allow you to "join" on any criteria you want: a join can only have a `[this] equals [that]` form. Move any criteria that doesn't match that pattern into a `where` clause. (This will not impact performance of the SQL query.)

Also, `group by` values need to be contained in a single (anonymous) object, not `&&`ed together.

```
var innerQuery = from fmr in context.VwMpidRecords
join fmrp in context.VwMpidRecordsProducts
on fmr.Id equals fmrp.Id
join fceh in context.VwCmpEventHistorys
on fmr.JobsiteCode equals fceh.JobsiteCode
where fmr.StartDate <= fceh.EndDate
where fceh.ClientNumber = @clientNumber
where fmrp.EmployerID != null && fmrp.EmployerCode != null
group fmrp by new {fmrp.EmployerID, fmrp.EmployerCode, fmrp.EmployerName};
```

Comment: I'm abandoning my answer and adding the remainder here: The unrecognized `fmrp` is due to the fact that it goes out of scope at the `into` clause.  It gets named `x` in the subsequent `from` clause. It can be reused, though: `from fmrp in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: I'm getting an error now on where fmrp.EmployerID != null && fmrp.EmployerCode != null where it says 'the name fmrp doesn't exist in the current context'

Comment: @user1186050 - Make the change I suggested. It addresses the unrecognized identifier errors.

Comment: so does that mean I use x instead of fmrp?

Comment: @user1186050 - You could do that, but the better thing to do would be reuse the name `fmrp` rather than calling it `x`. To reiterate, change `from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()` to `from fmrp in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: ok that works! How can I map the last part? What do I need to select to get a list of EmploerId, EmployerCode and EmployerName ?

Comment: @user1186050 `group x by new {x.EmployerID, x.EmployerCode, x.EmployerName} into empGroup select empGroup.Key;`

Comment: @user1186050: I don't understand the purpose of your `into gj` and the `x` variable. I think I'd just remove those. There are other signs that your query could perhaps be simplified more. Over time I've found that `join`s are rarely the best approach to use in LINQ, but I don't know your data model so it's hard to make more specific recommendations.